# Numbering data based on occurrence

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I need help in numbering data based on occurrence of a particular value.

Lets consider the input

```
Col1    Col2
1   a
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   a
6   1
7   4
8   a
9   2
10  3
```

I want to number them based on occurence of 'a' in col2. The output should look like

```
Col1    Col2    Result
1   a   1
2   1   1
3   2   1
4   3   1
5   a   2
6   1   2
7   4   2
8   a   3
9   2   3
10  3   3
```

Comment: Data doesn't have an order, other than that explicitly specified in a query.

Comment: So 1-4 and 5-7 and 8-10 are logical groups and you want to order by these groups?

Comment: Yes,  first occurrence of "a" should have value "1" in result and it should remain same until second occurrence of 'a'. Increment the result value based on occurrence of 'a' in col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor.

```
1) Create a temp table
2) Output the result to a cursor
3) Loop throught the cursor and update the temp table
4) Select from the temp table.
```

EDIT:

I dont know how useful this will be but this statement will get u what u want without using cursor.

```
SELECT [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      , (select count(*) from Table_1 where Col2 = 'a' and Col1 <= t1.Col1) 
  FROM [Table_1] t1
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to accomplish this in query, not with a PL/SQL Block

Comment: I have modified my answer please if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, with small changes i could use it for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @a table (Col1 int,Col2 Char(1))
Insert into @a Values (1,'a'),(2,'1'),(3,'2'),(4,'3'),(5,'a'),(6,'1'),(7,'4'),(8,'a'),(9,'2'),(10,'3');

;With CTE as
(
Select *,Row_Number() OVER (Order by Col1) as rn from @a
)


Select a.Col1,a.Col2,
(Select COUNT(Col2) from CTE a2 where a2.Col2=a.Col2 and a2.rn <= a.rn)
from CTE a
```

Answer (score 1):

As a note, in SQL Server 2012, you can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
select col1, col2,
       sum(case when col2 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by col1) as result
from t;
```

The cumulative sum is supported in other databases that support window/analytic functions as well.

Comment: Its much simpler with analytic function. Thank you.